# JSON Array union

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json

I have 2 JSON Array as below
Array 1:

```
[
    { id : 1, b: 1},
    { id : 2, b: 2},
    { id : 3, b: 3},
]
```

Array 2:

```
[
    { id : 1, c: 1},
    { id : 3, c: 3},
    { id : 4, c: 4}
]
```

And using nodejs code i need to union of both as below.

Union:

```
[
    { id : 1, b: 1, c:1},
    { id : 2, b: 2},
    { id : 3, b: 3, c:3},
    { id : 4, c: 4}
]
```

Could someone help the best possible way?

Comment: Loop through first array, check whether the 'id' value in first array is present in second array. If so, then take the extra key-value pairs from second array and add it to the current object in first array.

Comment: Do the "JSON" samples really have unquoted property names like `id` or `b` or `c`? Are there trailing commas like in the first sample? Not sure those samples really qualify being called JSON with that syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply join the two arrays and then use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to group the elements:

```js
let a1 = [ { id : 1, b: 1}, { id : 2, b: 2}, { id : 3, b: 3} ]
let a2 = [ { id : 1, c: 1}, { id : 3, c: 3}, { id : 4, c: 4} ]

let result = [...a1, ...a2].reduce((acc,cur) => {
  acc[cur.id] = {...acc[cur.id] || {}, ...cur}
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(result))
```